# How can I amplify my voice in real time just like a microphone does?

Tags: python, microphone

I am planning to make a microphone and speaker system to amplify my voice just like a normal microphone does.

I have a sound sensor and a speaker... is there any Python code that I can use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! This question is too broad. I suggest you look for some code examples and tutorials, and try them out. If you run into any specific problem, post it here. If you haven't yet, please check our site's [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

> to amplify my voice just like a normal microphone does.
>   I have a sound sensor and speaker.

Yes, you can use Rpi python to control both microphone and loudspeaker.  I have written python code to do that.  My python can play both recorded and real time input from microphone.

Let me briefly describe my hardware and software setup.

1. Microphone - This part does not need much control.  You just switch it on or off.  Of course you can do mixing sound/music/voice by hardware using op amp, or use analog multiplexing and demultiplexing input/output audio channels.
2. Amplifier - This part can be fiddled digitally, by Rpi python code.  For example, I am using a digital, class D power amplifier, less than 10W stereo. with digital gain control (those you find in TV or HiFi equipment, press a button to let volume go up or down in say 20 steps.)  You can also use a digital potentiometer (of course software control) to vary voltage which in turn controls the volume of the power amplifier.

All the hardware I have been playing are modules.  So you are basically doing module/system integration, no IC, not to mention transistors.

I forgot to mention that my very long term plan (5+ years) is to do voice recognition.  In case you are interested, I can recommend more references.

In case you have little idea where to start, I would suggest you to first get the following cheap things, and use linux audio libraries to play with them.

1. USB audio cable to connect Rpi to microphones and speakers.
2. Digital power amplifiers, say 2W.

[image: rpi usb sound card]

[image: pam8610 power amp]

/ to continue, ...

***References***

[USB Sound Card for Rpi - US$12](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Ugreen-USB-Sound-Card-USB-Audio-%5Burl%5DExtenal-USB-5-1-Sound-Card-Audio-Mic-Headphone-Jack/301635_32701486923.html?spm=2114.12010612.8148356.11.5b4d3f51ALwPZZ)

[Digital power amplifier - US$2.30](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DIY-PAM8610-Digital-HiFi-Power-Amplifier-Board-15W-15W-Small-Power-Mini-Audio-Amp-Kit-DC12V/32828586240.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.49.3c7422fdynOucR&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_5735015_317_5734915_10696_10084_453_10924_454_10083_10618_10920_10921_10307_10922_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_5735215_321_322_10103_5735115,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe-7&algo_pvid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe)

[PAM8610 10W Stero Class-D Audio Power Amplifier DC Volume Control](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8610.pdf)

[MCP4725 I2C DAC Breakout module US $0.82](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/MCP4725-I2C-DAC-Breakout-module-development-board/32294810362.html)

[SnowBoy Voice Recognition System](http://docs.kitt.ai/snowboy/)