# ADC with Raspberry pi to record sound

Tags: pi-2

I am trying to record sound through sound sensor module and I found that raspberry pi does not have analog input system. I bought an ADC chip (MCP3008) to convert analog to digital signal so that Raspberry pi can read sound. With python coding, I got digital signal between 0 and 1023 from the sound sensor. However, I wonder if I can record the sound and play it through speaker?

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> Rpi + ADC MCP3008 read sound from sound sensor get ADC results 0 and 1023
>
> can record the sound and play it through speaker?

***Answer***

Yes, no problem, if you can bear poor HiFi quality.  Since Rpi is an educational tool anyway, it should be a very good learning exercise.

Let me make some random comments.

> 1. You are using a "sound sensor" which I think is sort of a mini microphone with a mini power amplifier (***see Note 1 below***).  You might like to give a
>      weblink to make sure.
> 2. Human voice/music is roughly in the 20kHz range.  According to the information theory guys, to have HiFi quality without much information loss, you need to sample twice more frequent, ie,
>      40kHz.  MCP3008 with 200kps max can do without problem.
> 3. Now you log your ADC results in an array then to a text file.
> 4. To play back, so you DAC to play back.  (This is off topic, so no details here)

***Note 1***

A sound sensor can be a very low HiFi quality sound detector.  On the other hand many sound sensors are actually high HiFi quality Mike + Amp + AGC.  I once played with cheapy (US$2) MAX9814 modules and found it good for hobbyists.  But ***for better sound quality, see Note 2 below.***

[image: max 9814 mike amp agc]

***Note 2***

MCP3008 ADC is only 10 bit resolution, and the HiFi quality is very very poor.  I would suggest to try 12bit MCP3201/4/8.  Their python programming difficulty is almost the same.

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[MCP3008 [SPI, 10 bit, 200kps] Datasheet - MicroChip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21295c.pdf)

[How to amplify voice from microphone in real time? - Old Rpi StkEx post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96756/how-can-i-amplify-my-voice-in-real-time-just-like-a-microphone-does)

[How to make one MCP3008 A/D conversion? - Old Rpi StkEx post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96143/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-sampling-rate-of-1-ksps-when-interfacing-mcp3008-10-bit-a/96285#96285)

[Differences Between 16-Bit and 24-Bit Audio - Wesley Fenlon 2011mar03](https://www.tested.com/tech/1905-the-real-differences-between-16-bit-and-24-bit-audio/)

[MCP3201/04/08 12bit ADC Datasheets - Microchip](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf)